# Get text from html without id, name or class

Tags: html, vb.net

I want get some text from html and display it in a textbox, however the element with the text in doesn't have an id or name.

In the following example, I would like '100001063622219' to display in a textbox.

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 600px;">
<div id="success-wrap">
    <h1>Success!</h1>
    <p class="lead">
        Your Facebook personal numeric ID is:<br />
    </p>
    <code>100001063622219</code>
    <p>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">Find another &rarr;</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what about using tag? use javascript's getElementsByTagName() method.

Comment: how? i dont know tagname :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
//get the value of the first <code> tag in #success-wrap
    var code = document.getElementById("success-wrap").getElementsByTagName("code")[0]
    var str = code.innerHTML;
//put that string into #my-input input    
    document.getElementById("my-input").value = str;
//remove the original string in the <code> blocks
    code.parentNode.removeChild(code);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/L0fbcn72/

Comment: even better way `document.getElementById('success-wrap').getElementsByTagName('code')[0].innerHTML;` (in case if there more then one `code` tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) to get text between html tags (i.e `<code></code>`.

Here is the code example.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

 Function RegexTagGet(ByVal Input As String, ByVal TagName As String) As String
    Input = Regex.Match(Input, "<" & TagName & ">" & "[^\1]*?" & "</" & TagName & ">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value
    Input = Replace(Input, "<" & TagName & ">", "")
    Input = Replace(Input, "</" & TagName & ">", "")
    Return Input
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

     Dim html_source As String = "<code>100001063622219</code>"
     MsgBox(RegexTagGet(html_source, "code"))

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks its working but when i type other facebook username its showing 100001063622219 this. i want when i type other facebook username its showing other facebook id in textbox. here screenshot http://i.imgur.com/NF33hLJ.png

Comment: This is because you have to change `html_source` in my example this is fix. But you must have to grab webpage in html_source variable.